# Reading into linked list takes twice the time when also reading into hash table

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable, clock

Sorry about the title, this problem is quite hard to explain in one line. I have words being read from a .txt file and being placed into both a linked list and a hash table. I am also using a clock to record the time spent performing each function.

```
listclock = clock();
list = insertlist(list, word);
listclock = clock() - listclock;
listtime = listtime + listclock;

tableclock = clock();
table = inserttable(table, word);
tableclock = clock() - tableclock;
tabletime = tabletime + tableclock;
```

If I comment out the 2nd line where the insert list function is being called then I get the following values for tabletime and tableclock: 0s, and 0.03s

If I comment out the line with inserttable I get the following values: 6.34s and 0.02s

If I let them both run I get the following values: 12.39s and 0.04s

Is there a reason the time for executing the table function doubles when the hash table function is running also?

Insertlist function: (Inserttable function calls this):

```
List *insertlist(List *list, char word[30]) {
  List *templist = list;
  while(templist != NULL) {
    if(strcmp(templist->word, word) == 0) {
      templist->count++;
      list = addnode(list, word);
      list->count = templist->count;
      break;
    }
    templist = templist->next;
  }
  if(templist == NULL) {
    list = addnode(list, word);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: The answer is no. Where is listtime and tabletime being initialized?

Comment: care to share the `insertlist()` ?

Comment: at the start of that function I initialise both listtime and tabletime to 0.

Comment: I've added insertlist to the main question

Comment: The time might increase or decrease depending o the scheduling, processor architecture, memory speed, etc.

Comment: Yes but it consistently doubles when both functions are running, but when only one of them is the time is normal.

Comment: My guess: locality. If only one insert is called, you have all the data nicely close to each other, and it gets fetched into the cache well. If both inserts run, you always push out the list to fetch the hashtable and vice versa. Try running first the list insert for all words, and after that, the hashtable insert.

Comment: And what do you mean by "I let them both run"? Are you running them sequentially or in separate threads/processes?

Comment: This question is not constructive. Profile your code. Also, using `clock()` for performance measurement is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, what you suggested seems to have worked, the time to execute both is what it should be for insertlist, however for some reason now it's taking 0 seconds to execute the inserttable. Either way, that is another problem that I'll have a fiddle with, thanks for your suggestion.

askmish - I was commenting out the lines that executed each of the functions

Vlad - is there any other function I can use to take a measurement of time to execute? and I don't know what you mean by profile your code

Answer (score 0):

Values from clock can vary greatly. Also note that because you initialize tabletime at the top of the function it is timing both the insert and the tableinsert. If you are going to write your own benchmarks you should really have some setup and teardown code. In this case you should sample, say, each function 100 times and take the average. Between each sample you should clear all the data (and not count that in your timing).

But really, you need to back up and ask why are you doing this? Are you having complaints that the time to insert is taking too long so you are trying to decide between a linked list and a hashtable? That decision should be made not only based on how you add data but also on how you remove or access data. If you insert rarely and accesses often by a key, then you probably want a hashtable. If you need elements to be unique you should use a hashtable. If you insert often and always remove the first or last element then a list makes sense. All the time you spent on timing this one operation probably does not matter overall to your application. When approaching code, it is better to think in the large not in the small.

Comment: This is an assignment and we have been asked to investigate the benefit of a hash table over a linked list when counting words from a piece of a text. Thanks for the insight about when do use hash tables vs linked lists.

Comment: Joe, for what it's worth, you can figure a lot of this out without having to clock the code. Counting words is composed of several operations -- seeing if the word already exists in the collection, if it does then incrementing its count, if it doesn't then add it. That means many look ups. Basically, a look up for every word added. Which implementation do you think would be faster at finding a specific word? In a linked list you have to traverse the list until you find one, right? With a hash table, you hash the word once and find its bucket, only iterating through possible duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

A very nice benchmarking framework is given by [Jon Bentley](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/appmodels.html), to get usable data for "time this operation takes" isn't trivial.